# Format ImageLayout of each Image in DataSource before insert into DatagridviewImageColumn

Tags: winforms, datagridview, datagridviewimagecolumn

I have a table called "NHANVIEN" to display all employees and in my table i have a column with varbinary data type to store image of employee. I have written a method to get all employees and filled it into my DataGridView. But when the DataGridView was displayed the DataGridViewImageColumn always format my employee images to Stretch. 
I tried to user "for loop" to loop through my DataGridView and format my DataGridViewImageColumnCellLayout to Normal but nothing happened.

This is my method to fill my DataGridView

```
  private void FillGridViewThongTinNhanVien()
    {
        dgvThongTinNhanVien.Rows.Clear();
        dgvThongTinNhanVien.Columns.Clear();


        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn manv = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        manv.HeaderText = "Mã NV";
        manv.DataPropertyName = "MaNhanVien";//EmployeeID, the same name in database
        dgvThongTinNhanVien.Columns.Add(manv);
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn chucvu = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        chucvu.HeaderText = "Chức vụ";
        chucvu.DataPropertyName = "ChucVu";//the same column name in database
        dgvThongTinNhanVien.Columns.Add(chucvu);
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn tennv = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        tennv.HeaderText = "Tên NV";
        tennv.DataPropertyName = "HoTen";//the same column name in database
        dgvThongTinNhanVien.Columns.Add(tennv);
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn diachi = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        diachi.HeaderText = "Địa chỉ";
        diachi.DataPropertyName = "DiaChi";//the same column name in database
        dgvThongTinNhanVien.Columns.Add(diachi);
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn email = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        email.HeaderText = "Email";
        email.DataPropertyName = "Email";//the same column name in database
        dgvThongTinNhanVien.Columns.Add(email);
        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn gioitinh = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        gioitinh.HeaderText = "Giới tính";
        gioitinh.DataPropertyName = "GioiTinh";//the same column name in database
        dgvThongTinNhanVien.Columns.Add(gioitinh);
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn ngayvaolam = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        ngayvaolam.HeaderText = "Ngày vào làm";
        ngayvaolam.DataPropertyName = "NgayVaoLam";//the same column name in database
        dgvThongTinNhanVien.Columns.Add(ngayvaolam);
        DataGridViewImageColumn hinh = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
        hinh.HeaderText = "Hình";
        hinh.DataPropertyName = "Hinh";//the same column name in database
        hinh.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Normal;
        dgvThongTinNhanVien.Columns.Add(hinh);

        QLKSDataContext db = new QLKSDataContext();//LINQ to SQL class
        var ttNhanVien = db.spGetAllNhanVien();//get Employee list from Store Procedure

        byte[] image;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        Image img = Properties.Resources.NoImage;//set default image if the recieved image of each employee is null
        foreach (var nv in ttNhanVien)
        {
            if (nv.Hinh != null)
                image = (byte[])nv.Hinh.ToArray();
            else {
                    img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                    image = (byte[])(ms.ToArray());
                 }                                
            dgvThongTinNhanVien.Rows.Add(nv.MaNhanVien, nv.ChucVu, nv.HoTen, nv.DiaChi, nv.Email, nv.GioiTinh, nv.NgayVaoLam, image);                               
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < dgvThongTinNhanVien.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dgvThongTinNhanVien.Columns[i] is DataGridViewImageColumn)
            {
                ((DataGridViewImageColumn)dgvThongTinNhanVien.Columns[i]).ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Normal;
                break;
            }
        }
        //dgvThongTinNhanVien.DataSource = ttNhanVien;//Set datasource for DataGridView Employee
    }
```

Because my employees can insert no image so i have to cast those images to default image from my project resource and display it on DataGridView.

I used LinQ and Store Procedure to get information of all employees.
Was i wrong something. Please help me!.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am somewhat perplexed by the last for loop. It appears you are looping through the columns of the grid until you find a column of image type. Then, the code sets that columns image layout to normal. I do not understand why you would do this. You already “know” not only which column the image column is in (7), but also its name “Hinh”. Looping through the columns is simply a waste of time. Simply set the columns image layout as you do when creating it: `hinh.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Normal;`

Comment: I tested the code without the awkward for loop and it appears to work as expected, I am guessing you may not be reaching the second loop. Have you tried putting a breakpoint at the beginning of the second loop to see if it gets there and if so trace it from there.

Comment: I have tried to set break point and the index of DataGridViewImageColumn is true. I also removed the second loop and my images was still stretch when it displayed

Comment: If the image is stretched… then it is being stretched somewhere else. The posted code does not set the layout to stretch anywhere in the code…. Only normal… so something else is setting it to stretch.

Comment: I have a picture box to display image and its layout was stretch. But when i insert new record to my database and if i set my DataGridView with DataSource from the list record i get from my table "NHANVIEN" the image will display normal. The problem is if the image is null when I display it in DataGridView by set DataSource as you can see the last row in my method  I will get an error. So I have to cast the image if it is null before I display it in DataGridView

Comment: I can set DataSource with only last row in my method but I will get an error if some of my images is null in database. If I set DataSource directly from the list record i get from database all images layout will display Normal.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the problem. If you are using a `DataTable` as a data source to the grid and the `DataTable` has a column of type `Image`… it should not matter if the value is null. The data table will accept null values in an image cell, as will the grid. I am guessing you may have to edit your question to be more specific.